# Validation doesn't work after upgrade JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, unit-testing, jquery-plugins

Sorry, I don't have any work experience on the browser before,but we encounter a Unit test failed after we upgrade JQuery 1.7.1 to 1.8.3. I have to fix this failure. We have such html page.

```
          <li class="my-form-item">
            <label for="my_data_add_description" data-localize="my_data.add.description">Description</label>
            <div class="my-form-content my-has-help">
              <span type="text" id="my_data_add_description" name="data_description"></span>
              <label for="my_data_add_description" class="my-optional">optional</label>
              <label for="my_data_add_description" class="my-help" data-localize="my_data.add.description_help">Description</label>
            </div>
          </li>
```

And the JavaScript is like

```
var DATA_DESCRIPTION = 'data_description';

function getRules(formId) {
    var rules = {};
    rules[DATA_DESCRIPTION] = {
        maxlength: DataModel.DESCRIPTION_MAXLENGTH
    };
}

function getMessages(formId) {
    var messages = {};
    messages[DATA_DESCRIPTION] = {
        maxlength: Localizer.getString('data description maxLength')
    };
}

this.initValidator = function (formId) {

    // Set validation defaults per the 'dialog' context
    self.setDialogValidatorDefaults();

    validator = $(formId).validate({
        rules: getRules(formId),
        messages: getMessages(formId)
    });
};

Finally, we count the invalid elements number

this.invalidElements = function(formId) {
     $(formId).submit();
     return validator.invalidElements();
};
```

In the unit test. We set a string contains DESCRIPTION_MAXLENGTH+1 'a' to the my_data_add_description.

```
$(#my_data_add_description).val('aaa...a') // set DESCRIPTION_MAXLENGTH+1 'a' to my_data_description. 
expect(formValidator.invalidElements(formId)).toEqual(1); // now we have a invalid element
```

This test always fail and invalidElements always returns 0. This code works well when we use JQuery 1.7.1, but fails after we upgrade JQuery to 1.8.3. I can't understand why. Does anyone know about it or encounter similar problem?

Comment: Can u create a simple jsfiddle for your scenario

Comment: Validator plugin version?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `validate` is a plugin for jQuery, so it is likely to be using deprecated methods and functions. In order to fix this, you will also need to upgrade the `validate` plugin that you are using.

I cannot be sure which validate plugin you are using, but it is probably the following and if so, you can update it [here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Plugins/Validation&redirect=no).

However, before doing so, why are you even upgrading jQuery?? Whilst the latest version may have the latest features and better methods, unless you are writing new code that requires the latest version, do not upgrade as it is breaking your code!

Answer (score 0):

The current version of jquery validate plugin is 1.11.1 This supports *jquery 1.6.4, 1.7.2, 1.8.3, 1.9.0* If you are using an older version of the validator plugin you can [update it](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery-validation-1.11.1.zip)